# Create a map inside a list in Flutter/Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, dart-html

I want to create a MAP inside a list.

The result should be something like this

```
 [{date: 0, value: 0}, {date: 1, value: 0}, {date: 2, value: 0}, {date: 3, value: 0}, {date: 4, value: 0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the easiest way-

```
 List a=[];

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Map ab={};
    ab["date"]=i;
    ab["value"]=0;
    a.add(ab);
  }
```